# WP8 Remap unlock key to camera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Today my Nokia Lumia 520's power button decided to stop working. Same thing happened to my volume down key.

I know it is against MS's user experience guidelines to allow an application to lock the phone.

```
 Windows.Phone.System.SystemProtection.ScreenLocked = false;
```

Generates an error as expected, the property is readonly.

Is there anyway I can remap the lock key for **unlocking** the phone? Say something like

```
Microsoft.Devices.CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed;

private void CameraButtons_ShutterKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Unlock the phone
}
```

Or

Is it possible to swap the eventhandlers for the events?

Semi-Psuedo:

```
Microsoft.Devices.CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += Phone_Unlock_Event;

Phone_Unlock_Event += ShutterKeyPressed_Event;
```

Or finally could I swap the keycodes for the camera/power button?

Any help would be appreciated, currently have an expensive pretty brick sat on my desk..

Cheers!

Comment: Something like that would only work for a given app though.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate? A given app? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ahh I see, only work whilst the app was running?